# Как добавить <li> внутрь <ul> при помощи jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
var neededElements = $('.notopened');


$.each(neededElements, function(index, value) {
    $(value).bind("click", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.get("/Home/GetChildren?id=" + id, null, printDirectories);
        $(this).removeClass("notopened");
        $(this).addClass("opened");
    });
});

function printDirectories(data) {
    var it = data.Directories[0].ParentID;
    $('#' + it).after('<ul class="' + it + '">');
    $(it).insertAfter("<li>OLOLOLOLO</li>"); // здесь нужно вставить <li>
    $('#' + it).after("</ul>");
}
```

Как добавить `li` внутрь `ul` ?

Comment: зачем вы добавляете хэндлеры в цикле, если можно навесить на все сразу, вдобавок используете древний `bind` ?

Comment: нужно изменить вашь код?.. свой написать могу?

Comment: `$("li").wrap("ul");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в строке

```
$(it).insertAfter("<li>OLOLOLOLO</li>");
```

Необходимо дописать в селектор
('.' + it), потому что мы обращаемся к классу. Получится:

```
$('.' + it).append("<li>OLOLOLOLO</li>");
```

Comment: как бы `insertAfter` вставит после `insertBefore` вставит до - а именно обернуть это `wrap`

Answer (score 0):

Для добавления элемента внутрь другого в jQuery используется метод append():

```
$(it).append("<li>OLOLOLOLO</li>");
```

Comment: тоже не работает